# Problme in reading list of tuples into Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, tuples

I have my data in my csv file like this:

He has a dog,Allan
She has a cat,Sheena

I want to read it into a list of tuples in Python like this:
**[('He has a dog','Allan'),('She has a cat',Sheena')]**

My code is :

```
pos=[]
with open('C:\Python27\listx.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
 dreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
 for row in dreader:
     pos.append(tuple(row))
```

The output is :
**[('He has a dog,Allan',), ('She has a cat,Sheena',)]**

As you can see there are two problems:
1.the first entry has to be separated from the second by a ''..It has to be 'He has a dog',Allan' (There is a ' missing after dog and a ' missing before Allan)

2.An unwanted comma at the end of the last character in each tuple..

How do I remove these??..I would appreciate help-been stuck on this for a long time!!!

Comment: What are the backticks after your pos=[] for?

I've tried your code and I'm getting the output you wanted I think:

[('He has a dog', ' Allan'), ('She has a cat', ' Sheena')].

Is that correct?

Comment: @DasSnipez...sorry the backticks were a typo..nope I am not getting the desired output ..I have the same problems as before

Comment: Is the output I listed correct?

Comment: @DasSnipez...Yup-The output you listed is exactly what I want!!..Maybe there is something wrong in the way I write my csv file?.How have you written it in your csv file-each entry in a single cell right?

Comment: Have you used the same code that I used ?

Comment: I don't know much about csv files, I have just put 'He has a dog, Allan' on one line (without the quotes) and 'She has a cat, Sheena' on another, again without the quotes.

Comment: @DasSnipez That is exactly what I have as well..This is frustrating ..why is not coming as I want it to?.Im out of ideas !

Comment: @DasSnipez....Ok!!..I got it-He has a dog and Allan should be in separate cells in my Excel spreadsheet!!!..Phew..Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

If your task is to simply split each line by comma, you can forgo the csv reader and try this:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    pos = [tuple(s[1:-1] for s in line.strip().split(",")) for line in file]
```

Note the `strip()` on each line item - to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.

Also, a single item in a tuple is displayed with the extra comma such as `("Hello",)`

Comment: Your suggestion seemed to improve things:My output now is:

[('"He has a dog','Allan"'),('"She has a cat','Sheena"')]

How would i get rid of the " "??or should I just ignore it?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize there were quotes as well. You can substring line not to include quotes. So each line looks like `"He has a dog,Allan"`? Answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Nope This just gives me the output with the previous problem

Comment: It's odd. works ok on Unix ;) Are you using the newest version of Python 2.7 for Windows?